# Finding the request's URL in a Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a Lambda function which is called through an API Gateway using a URL. I need to return a variation of the request's URL by which the Lambda function was originally called in the response. How can I find the URL of the request in a Lambda function?

I was hoping I can pass the URL as a parameter to the Lambda function using API Gateway's mapping template. But I don't see how I can do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This body mapping template should give you all you need:

```
{
    "host" : "$input.params('Host')",
    "path" : "$context.path"
}
```

So, for where the url called was 'xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/stage/resource', this will pass an event into Lambda that looks like this:

```
{
    host: 'xxxxxxxxxx.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com',
    path: '/stage/resource' 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is not documented! Or at least I couldn't find it. Is there one for protocol? Like whether the request was called with `HTTP` or `HTTPS`?

Comment: API Gateway, won't accept http, only https, so kind of a moot point. But yes, there is one for protocol "$input.params('X-Forwarded-Proto')".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the **Use Lambda Proxy integration** you can piece it together from the event properties.  This is how I did it in python:

```py
host = event["headers"]["Host"]
path = event["requestContext"]["path"]
proto = event["headers"]["X-Forwarded-Proto"]
request_url = f"{proto}://{host}{path}"
```